# Configure how many containers are kept in Docker Swarm controlled by Portainer

Tags: docker-swarm, portainer

I don't know if Docker Swarm or Portainer manages the removal of old shutdown containers. But i want to **configure how many are kept**. It seems that currently 4 old instances are hold back per Slot (machine). When i update a service a new instance is spawned, the old instance gets shutdown and the oldest one gets deleted. Where is the setting for the count of *dead* containers per slot?

[image]

Comment: This is controlled by docker, and its related to the 'max_attempts' of the update_policy, in that setting that to a low number will reduce the number of history tasks retained.

Comment: Generally you want to set max_attempts to a value that best supports app stability rather than what looks pretty in portainer. A low setting might cause docker to halt your service if there is a transient error starting a new task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker swarm update --task-history-limit=5
```